# 'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command. PATH Env IS SET

Tags: javascript, path, environment-variables

I have a Javascript that includes

```
exec("powershell ..")
```

But this gives me the error

> Error: 'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

My PATH environment variable includes %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\which is the correct path of Powershell and I can execute Powershell from the cmd line

So why isn't it found from a Javascript?

Comment: What is this `exec` function? Is it from nodejs or some library/framework? If not, what does it do?

Comment: This is how the exec function is used (in unicorn.js) -   var process = exec("powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted \"" + syncScript + "\"", options, function (err, stdout, stderr) {